# Exclude subfolders and files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little problem with excludes files and subfolders.

```
for x in os.walk('core'):
  for y in glob.glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.py')):
    s = y.replace('\\', '.')
    x = s.replace('.py', '')
    cogs.append(x)
```

My code for taking all files from every folders and now i just want to exclude files `__init__`, `models` and subfolder `migrations` with files like `0002_auto` etc? Right now i just delete it from list manually like:

```
cogs.remove('core.rpg.models')
cogs.remove('core.rpg.__init__')
cogs.remove('core.rpg.migrations.__init__')
```

Comment: Do you just want to list the files of a particular directory..if so you can use this method import os
print(os.listdir('/path/to/folder/to/list'))..if not then please clearify your question a bit

Comment: My main folder is `core` and code above add to list from subfolders path to file, cogs print looks like
`['core.__init__', 'core.admin.admin', 'core.admin.purge',  'core.fun.gameinfos', 'core.fun.games', 'core.fun.otherfuncommands', 'core.rpg.models', 'core.rpg.migrations.__init__']` something like that, because it loaded scripts to discordbot, but like you can see it added files like `__init__` and added subfolder with files like `core.rpg.migrations.__init__` i just want have files from `core.rpg.script` without subfolder and without some files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would do `for root,dirs,files in os.walk('core'):` .. and operate on `dirs` or `files` and combine them with `root` to get the full path to them.

Using `glob` on top is akin to doing something to `x[2]` (aka `files` - wich is the list of files inside `root`)

```
import os

what_i_want = []
skip_files = {"__init__.py"}    

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('core'):
    for f in files:
        # skipe the subdirs models and migrations
        if root.endswith("models") or root.endswith("migrations"):
            continue
        # skip any non .py file
        if not f.endswith(".py"):
            continue
        # skip ceratain .py files
        if f in skip_files:
            continue
        # remove .py from filename
        f = f[:-3]

        # add filename including full root and subst \ to .
        what_i_want.append(os.path.join(root,f).replace("\\","."))
```

This would need some more slicing to only include the starting dir ("core") and not the full path to it.